# getting checkbox value

Tags: asp-classic

How do you get the value of a checkbox in Classic ASP?

```
<input style='border:none;' type='checkbox' name='chkEstimated' />
```

Comment: does this guy help http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/628239-checkbox-value-classic-asp-how-get-value

Answer (score 18):

Each checkbox should have a value attribute:

```
<input style='border:none;' type='checkbox' name='chkEstimated' value="1" />
```

When you:

```
Request.form("chkEstimated")
```

You will either get `1` (string), or nothing if it wasn't checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean when you post it to the server then it will only be posted if the checkbox is checked.

```
Request.Form("name-of-checkbox")
```

You can add a value attribute to your html markup if you would like but it is not necessary.